# Override the third party view for end-point

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using `Django-rest-framework-social-oauth2` , `convert-token` endpoint. This endpoints returns json as following

```
{
  "access_token": "************",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 36000,
  "refresh_token": "************",
  "scope": "read write"
}
```

Now I want to add `user id` or deta of `user model`(like name ,email,etc,,) to this json.

So I want to override the this view,maybe `class ConvertTokenView` in this [code](https://github.com/RealmTeam/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2/blob/master/rest_framework_social_oauth2/views.py).

How can I do this??

```
class ConvertTokenView(CsrfExemptMixin, OAuthLibMixin, APIView):
    """
    Implements an endpoint to convert a provider token to an access token
    The endpoint is used in the following flows:
    * Authorization code
    * Client credentials
    """
    server_class = SocialTokenServer
    validator_class = oauth2_settings.OAUTH2_VALIDATOR_CLASS
    oauthlib_backend_class = KeepRequestCore
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Use the rest framework `.data` to fake the post body of the django request.
        mutable_data = request.data.copy()
        request._request.POST = request._request.POST.copy()
        for key, value in mutable_data.items():
            request._request.POST[key] = value

        url, headers, body, status = self.create_token_response(request._request)
        response = Response(data=json.loads(body), status=status)

        for k, v in headers.items():
            response[k] = v
        return response
```

Comment: do you want to just change the response ?

Comment: You can tamper a bit with the body dictionary and add there the new fields before passing it to Response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must take two steps:

**Step 1:** Override the `ConvertTokenView` view to include your desired fields as such:

```
class MyCustumConvertTokenView(CsrfExemptMixin, OAuthLibMixin, APIView):
    """
    Implements an endpoint to convert a provider token to an access token
    The endpoint is used in the following flows:
    * Authorization code
    * Client credentials
    """
    server_class = SocialTokenServer
    validator_class = oauth2_settings.OAUTH2_VALIDATOR_CLASS
    oauthlib_backend_class = KeepRequestCore
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Use the rest framework `.data` to fake the post body of the django request.
        mutable_data = request.data.copy()
        request._request.POST = request._request.POST.copy()
        for key, value in mutable_data.items():
            request._request.POST[key] = value

        url, headers, body, status = self.create_token_response(request._request)

        # You can add your desired fields here:
        data=json.loads(body)
        data['username'] = request.user.username 
        response = Response(data, status=status)

        for k, v in headers.items():
            response[k] = v
        return response
```

**Step 2**: Modify your `urlconf` to make `convert-token` endpoint to point to your new view

```
    url(r'^convert-token/?$', MyCustumConvertTokenView.as_view(), name="convert_token"),
```

**Note 1**: In your `views.py` where you are re-writing this `ConvertTokenView`, you must import all the necessary modules from the original package.

**Note 2**: In your `urlsconf` make sure this newly-added URL is on top of the URL related to the oauth2 package.

Comment: Thank you it' quite great explanation. I thought I should do some inheritance. but I just simply need to make alternation.